# Text Box in Outlook Email

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

Below are two sets of VBA code that deletes text boxes, the first one works in MS Excel and the second in MS Word. The only difference between the two is the third line after "Active".

I'm trying to duplicate this action in MS Outlook in a new-opened email but lack the knowledge of the proper code terminology... is there anyone out there that knows the answer to this?... thank you,.

```
Sub RemoveTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub RemoveTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible, as Outlook email bodies are HTML documents (but rendered by Word's layout engine) that does not expose any DOM or means of adding interactive controls (ActiveX COM or otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For Outlook it will look like the following Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Shp As Word.Shape

    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor

    For Each Shp In wdDoc.Shapes

        Debug.Print Shp.Type 'msoTextBox = 17 - Print on Immediate Window
        If Shp.Type = msoTextBox Then Shp.Delete

    Next

End Sub
```

*For open email work with **[Application.ActiveInspector Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** and **[Inspector.WordEditor Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196.aspx)***

> *<sub>**[Inspector.WordEditor Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196.aspx)** Returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. Read-only, The WordEditor property is only valid if the IsWordMail method returns True and the EditorType property is olEditorWord. The returned WordDocument object provides access to most of the Word object model except for the following members:</sub>*
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Application.ActiveInspector Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** Returns the topmost **[Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869356.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** object on the desktop.</sub>*

---

***[Remember to add reference to word xx object library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx)***

---

> *<sub>1. From the Tools menu, choose References to display the References dialog box.</sub>*
>
> *<sub>2. The References dialog box shows all object libraries registered with the   operating system. Scroll through the list for the application whose object library you want to reference. If the application isn't listed, you can use the Browse button to search for object libraries (</sub>*.olb and *.tlb) or executable files (*.exe and *.dll on Windows). References whose check boxes are checked are used by your project; those that aren't checked are not used, but can be added.*

Comment: Thank you for your response... I'm a bit confused, you said it's not possible yet you provided code. Are you saying it's not possible to do it the way it works with Excel & Word and that your code does work with Outlook? If this is the correct understanding then maybe you can offer a little more help... when I run the code it errors out at the first wdDoc.

Comment: @DennisTM I'm not the one who said that - it was someone else see the comments again - now I have never seen anyone do this on Outlook so I have written one for you using ms-word object library and it works- I will never post code with out testing- I'm on Outlook 2010

Comment: Man, you are "The Wizard"... the reference to Word 14.0 Object Library did it, I am a smarter person as of today. What a relief, I was about to pack it in and just resolve myself to the fact that this couldn’t be done... thank you very much