# How to insert a textbox into an Outlook e-mail

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I generate Outlook e-mails from VBA as part of an automation process and I am struggling to insert textboxes to the e-mail body in the code.

The textboxes would be at a specific position serving commentary purposes. First, I planned to include them as tables but those alter the layout of the body, which I would like to avoid.

Then I looked into overlay methods like z-orders to no avail.

Is it possible to insert an overlaid textbox into a specific position of the e-mail body from VBA? In Outlook this can easily be done through insert/textbox /draw textbox.

Comment: Textbox is a winforms object but it sounds like you are talking about an HTML element? Are you trying to add an input field? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_text.asp

Comment: Do be aware that you have no control over how your email will appear on the recipient's system. Whilst the layout & formatting might look great at your end, they could look anything but at the recipient's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is quick example on how to add textbox to Outlook email*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor

    'Add a text box
    Dim Shp As Word.Shape
    Set Shp = wdDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox _
                    (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                    Left:=100, Top:=75, Width:=150, Height:=200)


    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

***[Remember to add reference to word xx object library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709)***

***[See how to delete as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44059865/4539709)***

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! One thing to add, if others were looking at this question, is that I had to add the reference for outlook xx.x object library as well for the code to run and changed the Application.ActiveInspector() to Outlook.ActiveInspector as from VBA it did not register Outlook as the main application but rather Excel.